# ARP header data in a Two machine network

Tags: networking, arp

I connected two machines via a network cable.  I need to get an ARP request data via Wireshark.  When I pinged the IP of the other machine, I get the ARP request on Wireshark.  But, it is not broadcasting a message.  It targets pinged IP address directly.  I think a LAN with only two machines does not need to do a broadcast.  Am  I right?  Can any one explain this to me?

Comment: Did you connect through a hub or use a cross-over cable?

Answer (score 1):

Always in ARP packet, MAC address will be broadcast not IP. As it is used to learn MAC address of other host whose IP address is known, ARP packet needs to have valid IP address rather than broadcast IP. You can check ARP packet example at below path:

http://wiki.wireshark.org/AddressResolutionProtocol

Hope this clears your doubt.